# Конец списка ListView; Событие для Scrolled

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, uwp

По умолчанию список показывает десять эллементов.

Необходимо:

1. Узнать если список прокрутился до конца
2. Продолжить Итерацию, чтобы показать следующие десять элементов

```
<ListView
x:Name="ListView"
Scrolled="ListView_Scrolled"
ItemsSource="{Binding ListTotal}"              
CachingStrategy="RecycleElementAndDataTemplate"
HorizontalOptions="Fill"
VerticalOptions="Fill">......</ListView>
```

```
private void ListView_Scrolled(object sender, ScrolledEventArgs e)
{           
    // что делать здесь (???)
    
    имеются переменные (в viewModel-е): 

    1. ListTotal (список из 1000 элементов)
    2. Take10 (чтобы по умолчанию показывать 10 элементов)
    3. PageIndex (изначально равна -1, затем ++ и умножаю на Take10 на 10, что позволяет показать 10 элементо по умолчанию)
    
    // данное событие в CodeBehind=ContentPage, но возможно сделать байндинг для вызова комманды из вью модели, но впринципе доступ к переменным имеется
}
```

вопрос все тот же >>> как узнать, что пользователь дошел-доскролил до конца списка. вопрос второй у меня будет позже, но скорей всего легче, как показать следующие 10 элементов, скорей всего Take10++, но это не суть.
Сейчас не могу построить правильный if в моем событии, которое запускается когда просто скролишь.

Мне бы хотелось иметь внутри события if, который позволил узнать **конец отображаемого списка**.
[Тот же вопрос на .com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62404737/end-of-listview-xaml-listview-scrolled-new-event-codebehind-listview-scrolle?noredirect=1#comment110367941_62404737)

Comment: Наверное `ScrolledEventArgs` содержат необходимую информацю о прокрутке, а `sender` - это собственно сам экземпляр `ListView`, ему можно сделать каст и обращаться к его свойствам. Далее смотреть позицию скролла, и если она максимальная, закидывать новые элементы в список (желательно асинхронно).

Comment: `if(viewModel.PageIndex(изначально равен -1) < e.ScrollY)
             { //прибавляю и = 0,1,2... итд
                viewModel.PageIndex++;
                 //прибавляю количество страниц
                viewModel.PageSize10++;
                //пытаюсь узнать чему равен игрек
                Debug.WriteLine(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>ScrollY_UP=>" + ListView.Y);}
    else
              {viewModel.PageIndex--;
                //пытаюсь узнать чему равен игрек
                Debug.WriteLine(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>ScrollY_DOWN=>" + ListView.Y);}`
**Как узнать максПозицию вопрос**

Comment: Добавьте эту информацию в вопрос, используйте кнопку Править. Я пока не знаю ответа.

Comment: Для начала получите экзкмпляр ListView из sender `ListView myListView = sender as ListView`, затем обращайтесь к свойству `myListView.ScrollView.ScrollableHeight` (если не работает, найдите другой способ обратиться к `ScrollView`). Это то что я увидел в [документации](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.scrollviewer.scrollableheight?view=winrt-19041#Windows_UI_Xaml_Controls_ScrollViewer_ScrollableHeight).

Comment: Спасибо Вам за ответ и документацию. Вопрос в том, что я работаю не на чистом UWP, а кроссплотформенном приложении. и я попыталась интегрировать данную документацию, но нет доступа к тем или иным компонентам к сожалению. Поэтому вопрос есть ли эквивалент для UWP xamarin forms ?

Comment: Если это Xamarin Forms, поставьте сообтествующий тег к вопросу.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вопрос закрыт, спасибо всем.

Дело в том, что при использовании кроссплатформенного приложения не все элементы работают корректно в UWP и чтобы сделать корректный скроль нужно постараться.

[тут можно посмотреть что работает, а что еще на стадии разработки](https://gist.github.com/hartez/7d0edd4182dbc7de65cebc6c67f72e14)
[а тут говорится про несправность коллектионВью](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/9013#issuecomment-579163231)

Таким образом, решение это создать клиентский класс, который будет расчитывать конец листа где есть переменная конец листа, и если она = истина запускать комманду по загрузке следующих эллементов из общего списка. Ответ, который дан [тут](https://github.com/david-js/XFListViewInfo) очень помог.
и [вот тоже](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/infinite-scrolling-listview-for-xamarin-forms-app-using-behaviors/) интересное решение.

[подробней](https://criticalhittech.com/2017/11/14/observing-listview-scrolling-in-xamarin-forms/)

```
public class MyListView : ListView
{
    public static readonly BindableProperty
        LastScrollDirectionProperty =
            BindableProperty.Create(nameof(LastScrollDirection),
            typeof(string), typeof(MyListView), null);
    public static readonly BindableProperty
        AtStartOfListProperty =
            BindableProperty.Create(nameof(AtStartOfList),
            typeof(bool), typeof(MyListView), false);

    public string LastScrollDirection
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(LastScrollDirectionProperty); }
        set { SetValue(LastScrollDirectionProperty, value); }
    }

    public bool AtStartOfList
    {
        get { return (bool)GetValue(AtStartOfListProperty); }
        set { SetValue(AtStartOfListProperty, value); }
    }
}
```